# How To Get Values of Variable For All Instances of A Class

Tags: python, class, object

I have a Python class with thousands of instances.

Each instance holds several variables.

I need to retrieve the values of a specific list variable for of all instances of the class.

I believe it's done with...

```
__dict__
```

I just can't seem to get the syntax right to get the data I need.

I know it's a simple 1 line of code.  Anyone know what that code is?

Comment: you need to show an example of your try and class !

Comment: There is no way to get a list of all instances of a class. You will have to maintain such a list manually. The `weakref` module might be a help for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Klaus D says, you should maintain a manual list. However, if all these instances exist in the local scope of one function, then the code below shows how you can get at them. But even though it's possible, I *strongly* advise you **not** to do this sort of thing.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import random

class myclass():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

def main():
    random.seed(42)

    #Create some instances of myclass
    for i in range(10):
        s = "a%02d = myclass(%d)" % (i, random.randint(0, 99))
        print s
        exec(s) in globals(), locals()

    #Extract all instances of myclass from the locals() dict
    instances = dict((k, v) for k, v in locals().items() if isinstance(v, myclass))

    for name in sorted(instances.keys()):
        print "%s : %2d" % (name, instances[name].data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**output**

```
a00 = myclass(63)
a01 = myclass(2)
a02 = myclass(27)
a03 = myclass(22)
a04 = myclass(73)
a05 = myclass(67)
a06 = myclass(89)
a07 = myclass(8)
a08 = myclass(42)
a09 = myclass(2)
a00 : 63
a01 :  2
a02 : 27
a03 : 22
a04 : 73
a05 : 67
a06 : 89
a07 :  8
a08 : 42
a09 :  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all the variables of the object with [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars):

> Return the `__dict__` attribute for a module, class, instance, or any other object with a `__dict__` attribute.

So, just pass object to `vars` as a parameter:

```
vars(obj)
```